# WPF Create Video with AForge

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge

After hours spend on google all I found are tutorials for Windows Forms and I am using WPF.

To capture the screen I use AForge libary. The code to catch video from camera and show it in Image control is below:

```
private void Record_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_finalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                _finalVideo.Stop();
            }

            _finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(_cameraDevices[CamerasList.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);

            _finalVideo.NewFrame += (s, a) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Image img = (Bitmap)a.Frame.Clone();

                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
                    bitmapImage.EndInit();
                    bitmapImage.Freeze();
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
                        CameraStream.Source = bitmapImage;
                    }));
                }
                catch
                {
                    // exception
                }
            };

            _finalVideo.Start();
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can save on disc as video file?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you 
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/ffmpeg.html

In short aforge doesnt provide itself video recording itself but its done trough ffmpeg, should be part of the afforge download.

Lol i see so often WPF, while i need forms, several times i converted wpf code to form code, on average WPF has better graphics handeling (supports more RGB formats) .

If you just quickly need to convert a range of images to a movie
you might check virtualdub, it can convert movies like 001.png 002.png 003.png..etc to avi   (virtualdub is free).

Comment: Great but I dont have VideoFileReader class C# :(

Comment: check this http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d3528599-8bf2-f041-d9f9-96c2204c1c2a.htm